# uplink port from switch to router?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have a switch with a number of devices plugged into it. It connects to a 4-port router that provides internet.

Long story short, the network is in a cluterfrak, and I'm troubleshooting. To network the switch and the router together, I don't need to use the switch's uplink port, right? The router just plugs into it like another device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the router/switch. Some of them will autosense uplink ports, and some require you to make use of it. Either look up the switch and router and check, or just plug it in and test.

Answer (score 3):

If your switch has a marked uplink port, use it!

If it's marked it's unlikely it is autodetecting.

edit:

You probably should tell us how your setup is working right now.  Is it

```
Modem -> Router -> Switch
```

or

```
Modem -> Switch -> Router
```

If it's `Modem -> Switch -> Router` then it does not need to be in the uplink port.  If it is `Modem -> Router -> Switch` then you need to connect to the uplink port, and if it is marked as "Uplink" you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the switch.  Some switches have autosensing ports and you can use whatever port you want.  Others you have to use the uplink port.  Some details on the router/switch and the "clusterfrak" and more help could be offered...